# JavaScript: how to return false to link without breaking function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hyperlink, break

I have a question (surprisingly ;) ):

How can I return false to a link without breaking the function?
I did this previously without jQuery, back then I set an animation to execute after an interval and returned false. This time I need the function to continue running.

```
function initNavLinks(){
    navLinks = $("div#header a").click(function(){
        return false;
        processSlideReq();
    })
}
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't just swap the lines around and do:

```
function initNavLinks(){
    navLinks = $("div#header a").click(function(){
        processSlideReq();
        return false;
    })
}
```

?

Comment: Yes, then it calls processSlideReq function, which in turn calls a function that animates stuff. Untill it finishes running those functions, the browser will follow the link.

Comment: @Dean - are you sure? Nothing should happen until the click handler returns.

Comment: Oh sorry sorry, the function was unfinished. Thanx it works fine :)

Comment: @Dean - functions that animate stuff in jQuery return immediately. Can you show an example of `return false` not working?

Comment: @Dean - Ok, ignore my last comment then :)

Answer (score 6):

You probably should just prevent the event's default action like this:

```
function initNavLinks(){
    navLinks = $("div#header a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        processSlideReq();
    })
}
```

You may want to read jQuery's [Event Object documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and [bind documention](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to understand the differences between of returning false, calling preventDefault() and calling stopPropogation() within event handlers.

Comment: preventDefault() is not supported by IE

Comment: Where do you see that ? Are you talking about IE's default Event object ? Because jQuery's Event::preventDefault() has been around since version 1 and normalized accross all browsers. Here's an example of it that works for me in IE7 http://jsbin.com/olefe3/2

Comment: Thanx, Il check that out, sry I didnt realize yu were talking about jQuery's :preventDefault()

Answer (score 1):

Just as a theoretical curiosity, you could also use [JavaScript 1.7's generator support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7) (though it only works in Firefox and wouldn't apply for links).

```
function x() {
    yield false;
    yield doSomething();
}

first_return_value = x();
second_return_value = x();
```